# Apache .htaccess Syntax Specification

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

This is a dumb question, but is there a syntax specification for the Apache .htaccess file format?

All I can find are "tutorials", that is **not** what I want.

What I want is a list of all the valid keywords that will be recognized in a .htaccess file and what all the valid parameters and functions are. Does this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.htaccess is a way to put a `<Directory>` specification inside a file which is in this directory.

So every Apache documentation settings that is tagged as available at a `Directory Levels` is available on a .htaccess. Fore example take a look at [ErrorDocument documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) you have in the main box a *Context* settings, here we can see this context contains 'Directory', so it's available on a .htaccess. That means as well that if you have access to apache configuration it's better in term of performances to use a `<Directory /my/dir>` section than a `.htaccess` in `/my/dir`. As you could forbid .htaccess and avoid file system reads. When you use .htaccess files Apache is looking for a .htaccess in your directory and all parent directories.

Now, I just said you can forbid .htaccess files, you do that with:

```
AllowOverride None
```

Which means .htaccess files cannot override any configuration setting (and Apache will stop looking for these files on the filesystem). **AllowOverride** can take [other values](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride), and that mean some of the *available* settings **won't be available in your .htaccess** if the apache admin do not want you to break everything.

**Edit:**

for a quick reference, which is the main point, you have this [table in apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/quickreference.html), where all directives are listed, check the *'d'* for directory, and you have your .htaccess reference.

Answer (score 2):

an .htaccess file takes pretty much a good chunk of whatever your main apache config can take. I doubt there is going to be a page that lists everything that can go in one. Pretty much any module you can load into apache, you can use that module's config in a .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

> .htaccess files provide a way to make
>   configuration changes on a
>   per-directory basis.
>
> In general, .htaccess files use the
>   same syntax as the main configuration
>   files.
>
> Apache configuration files contain one
>   directive per line. The backslash "\"
>   may be used as the last character on a
>   line to indicate that the directive
>   continues onto the next line. There
>   must be no other characters or white
>   space between the backslash and the
>   end of the line.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/configuring.html#syntax

Comment: Copy/paste much?

Comment: .......Yea, so?

Comment: Well - it's not *your* answer. You're taking material written by another organization and passing it off as your own. That's not acceptable. If you're going to copy/paste, at least come out and acknowledge that you're doing so and give attribution where appropriate.

Comment: Where do you get your information from?

Comment: What information?

Comment: Information about what is acceptable.

Comment: From the [horse's mouth](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54558/would-it-be-wrong-to-copy-paste-questions-from-quora/54559#54559). Just use common sense - give fair attribution and all is well.

Comment: Wow, you truly lack reading comprehension skills.  Good luck to you.

Comment: @dmourati - Dispense with the insults, please. I've been around here for a while, and have seen *many* users come in and submit copy/paste answers. They're very easy to spot (which is how I spotted yours) and without fail, the answers get deleted if there's no attribution. The community deserves better than that. It doesn't look like you've made a habit out of submitting copy/paste answers, which is great! There's a reason that all of the top-ranked answers are 100% custom written by SF users.